# R - Faster way of creating conditional sums as new column in data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

**My initial problem**

I have a data frame of hospital visits that looks like this:

```
df = data.frame(PNUM = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
                indate=as.Date(c("2016-01-03","2016-05-05","2017-02-03",
                                 "2017-06-07","2016-01-03","2016-05-05",
                                 "2017-02-03","2017-06-07")),
                Inpatient=c(0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0),
                AnE=c(1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1))
```

Output:

```
  PNUM     indate Inpatient AnE
1    1 2016-01-03         0   1
2    1 2016-05-05         1   0
3    1 2017-02-03         0   1
4    1 2017-06-07         1   0
5    2 2016-01-03         1   0
6    2 2016-05-05         1   0
7    2 2017-02-03         1   0
8    2 2017-06-07         0   1
```

I now want to add columns that reflect the number of "Inpatient" and "AnE" visits in the 365 days prior to the current "indate". The desired result looks like this:

```
  PNUM     indate Inpatient AnE sum_365_Inpatient sum_365_AnE
1    1 2016-01-03         0   1                 0           0
2    1 2016-05-05         1   0                 0           1
3    1 2017-02-03         0   1                 1           0
4    1 2017-06-07         1   0                 0           1
5    2 2016-01-03         1   0                 0           0
6    2 2016-05-05         1   0                 1           0
7    2 2017-02-03         1   0                 1           0
8    2 2017-06-07         0   1                 1           0
```

I have found a way to do this (see below) but it is very slow (~ 4 min for 1 new column with 10,000 rows). My original data frame has 2 mio rows and >100 columns for which I want to create these sums. I'm relatively new to R, and created the below solution by putting together things from several similar problems. I guess it's not very efficient. I would be grateful for any suggestions of how to improve my code.

**Here is my very inefficient solution**

I first define a function that calculates the sum of a specific column looking back X days (addtionally restricted by ID as I only want events from the same person)

```
# Function definition

hist_sum = function(colname,ID,date_input,x) { 
    # window start and end
    window_start = date_input - x
    window_end = date_input
    # Calculate sum within window
    sum(df[(df$PNUM == ID) & (df$indate >= window_start) &
           (df$indate < window_end),c(colname)])
}


# Vectorise function

hist_sum = Vectorize(hist_sum)
```

I then use a for loop and dplyr's mutate function to calculate the sums for "Inpatient" and "AnE" columns, using PNUM as ID, indate = as event date, a window of 365 days (and create a unique column name for each):

```
library(dplyr)

for (i in c("Inpatient","AnE")) {
    # Generate column title
    coltitle = paste("sum",as.character(j),i,sep="_")
    # Apply 
    df = mutate(df, !!coltitle := hist_sum(i,PNUM,indate,365))
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A non-equi join is designed to do this.

**For the case of mutually exclusive dummy columns...**

First, some setup...

```
# go to long form

library(data.table)
DT = melt(setDT(df), id=c("PNUM", "indate"), variable.name = "status")[value == 1, !"value"]
setorder(DT, PNUM, indate)

# use integer dates

DT[, indate := as.IDate(indate)]


   PNUM     indate    status
1:    1 2016-01-03       AnE
2:    1 2016-05-05 Inpatient
3:    1 2017-02-03       AnE
4:    1 2017-06-07 Inpatient
5:    2 2016-01-03 Inpatient
6:    2 2016-05-05 Inpatient
7:    2 2017-02-03 Inpatient
8:    2 2017-06-07       AnE
```

Count 'em

```
for (s in unique(DT$status)){
  DT[, paste0("n365_", s) := 
    .SD[status == s][.SD[, .(PNUM, d_dn = indate - 365L, d_up = indate)], 
      on=.(PNUM, indate >= d_dn, indate < d_up),
      .N, by=.EACHI]$N
 ][]
}

   PNUM     indate    status n365_AnE n365_Inpatient
1:    1 2016-01-03       AnE        0              0
2:    1 2016-05-05 Inpatient        1              0
3:    1 2017-02-03       AnE        0              1
4:    1 2017-06-07 Inpatient        1              0
5:    2 2016-01-03 Inpatient        0              0
6:    2 2016-05-05 Inpatient        0              1
7:    2 2017-02-03 Inpatient        0              1
8:    2 2017-06-07       AnE        0              1
```

---

*How it works.* Written more verbosely:

```
for (s in unique(DT$status)){
  DT[, paste0("n365_", s) := {

    # define the ranges we are interested in
    look_these_up = .SD[, .(PNUM, d_dn = indate - 365L, d_up = indate)]

    # define where we are looking
    look_in_here = .SD[status == s]

    # do the lookup
    # counting rows of look_in_here (.N)
    look_in_here[look_these_up, on=.(PNUM, indate >= d_dn, indate < d_up),
      .N, by=.EACHI]$N
 }][]
}
```

The syntax for a data.table join is `x[i, on=, j]` where we use the `on=` rules to look up each row of `i` in `x` and then do `j`. See `?data.table` for details.

---

**For the case of possibly overlapping dummy columns...**

This possibility was brought up by the OP in a comment. In this case, we can't go to long form and collapse to a single "status" column.

```
library(data.table)
DT = data.table(df)
mycols = setdiff(names(DT), c("PNUM", "indate"))

# use integer dates
DT[, indate := as.IDate(indate)]

# use integer dummies
DT[, (mycols) := lapply(.SD, as.integer), .SDcols=mycols]

DT[, paste0("n365_", mycols) := {
  # define the ranges we are interested in
  look_these_up = DT[, .(PNUM, d_dn = indate - 365L, d_up = indate)]

  lapply(mycols, function(s){
    # define where we are looking
    look_in_here = .SD[get(s) == 1L]

    # do the lookup, counting rows of look_in_here (.N)
    look_in_here[look_these_up, on=.(PNUM, indate >= d_dn, indate < d_up),
    .N, by=.EACHI]$N
  })
 }][]
```

Generally, joins/lookups are faster against integers than floating point numbers, which is why that conversion is done here. The `lapply` and `for` loop ways are equivalent, though the `lapply` way only involves constructing `look_these_up` once, and so may be faster.

Comment: Wow. That looks good. However, is it possible to do this with my original dummy variables instead of the status? As I mentioned in my post, I have 100 variables and most of them are not mutually exclusive (e.g. it is also possible that one row is "AnE" as well as "Inpatient"). Sorry, I don't have any experience with data.table syntax and can't figure it out.

Comment: Ah ok, sure; I'll edit. I didn't notice that they might not be mutually exclusive.

Comment: Thank you very much. The second version works perfectly.